# Cycles Renders A Black Frame At End (Render Layers is Connected to Composite)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Cycles seems to render fine for a while and then all of a sudden turns into a black frame. This only happens when rendering with cycles, evee works fine.

Ive tried everything that I found on the web. As I said in the title i've turned on Use Nodes in Compositing Render; Layers is Connected to Compositing so thats not the issue. If i cut the connection and reconnect it and render again still doesnt work. I've loaded factory settngs re installed Blender. I've turned off Scene>Post Processing>Composting. still doesnt work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

These are the settings that I used for this current render. Its the factory defaults and the tips that i've seen on the internet.

Its the default scene so nothing should be in the way.

[image]

The Resulting Render

[image]

Ive tried both the Supported and Experimental Feature set I installed and configured CUDA and it sure made the render faster but the black screen remains. I opened Blender in terminal with the --debug-all flag and the result of the render is:

[image]

This has largely been the case if i keep the render frames at 4096 and it always gets to around 1500 and then turns black if i lower the render frames it works till the last frame then like clockwork turns black.

[image]

This is what compositing looks like after the render finishes. I'm on Linux Mint and I installed blender with the system package in the Linux Mint Software Manager if that makes any difference I have a NVIDIA 970 if that might've caused the issue being on a Linux system with a NVIDIA GPU and all. Honestly have no clue, been trying to fix it for days; maybe im just not a good enough googler. if you want any more info just ask.

Answer (score 0):

My fans are facing the correct direction. I figured it out though and it was in the blender settings. Denoise was on but there is no option for the Denoiser, its just blank, passes has a few options by default it was on Albedo and Normal.

[image]

When I turn off Denoiser it cycles renders fine obviously not denoised but whatever. Basically I dont have optix or the Open image denoiser installed probably cuz its not packaged in with my linux distro. You can download them online ill give it a shot. Ill edit again if it worked out.